# Website not correctly displaying "Not Found - The requested URL was not found on this server."

Tags: weblinks

I designed my website with the Nicepage tool, and published it on my own domain. The homepage is correctly displaying, but when I try to click on the menu or any other on the website, I get the message : "Not Found - The requested URL was not found on this server."

I tried to contact Nicepage but they can't seem to help.

What should I do ?

Comment: What Joomla version do you use?

Answer (score 0):

If you have configured "Use URL Rewriting" to "Yes" in Joomla's Global Configurations under [Site] > "SEO", then you need to **rename Joomla's htaccess.txt to .htaccess** (which is needed for the URL rewriting).